# The URL is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web?

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, file-upload

I am trying to upload documents to SharePoint 2010 site and i am getting the following error.

> The URL 'aaa.pdf' is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or
>   folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current
>   Web

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried this solution from Microsoft? 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2796640/-the-url-file-name-is-invalid-error-message-when-you-upload-a-file-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably happen in following case. Please check some checkpoint to solved this error:

SharePoint Database Server should have minimum 1 GB free space.

SharePoint Site application pool user/password is not expired.

Reset IIS and Recycle Application Pool of SharePoint site.

This will solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

To narrow down the issue:

1. Do all libraries have this issue?
2. Check for the ULS logs, which will tell you more information.

Browse to the content database for the site in the SQL Server Management Studio
Expand 'Databases' and right-click on the content database to select "Properties".

Select "Options" from the left pane in the pop-up window.

The option "Auto Create Statistics" must be set to "False". If it is set to "True", it must be toggled to "False".